# Spark Structured Streaming : mapPartitions is supported?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is it possible to use mapPartitions in Spark Structured streaming ?

Running into these errors

option 1:

```py
dataframe_python.mapPartitions(processfunction)
```

'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'mapPartitions'

option 2:

```py
dataframe_python.rdd.mapPartitions(processfunction);
```

'Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();

is there a way to use mapPartitions for my scenario ? my intention is to transform the existing dataframe to another dataframe while minimizing the calls to external resource API by sending batch of rows.

For example processfunction will look like below :

```py
processfunction(rows):

 batch = list(rows)
 results = call_external_resource(batch)
 for row in rows 
  tmp_row = rows[i]
  tmp_row["new_column"] = results[i]
  yield Row(**tmp_row)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using pyspark API, you may not be able to use mapPartitions directly on a dataframe, using Spark scala API you will be able to do it.

In your case you are using spark 2.4 or above then you may use `foreachBatch` to do something like this.

```
def map_partition_func(rows):
    row_list = list(rows)
    for row in row_list:
        yield row

def foreach_batch_func(df, epoch_id):
    # Transform and write batchDF
    mapPartOutput = df.rdd.mapPartitions(map_partition_func) 


mapPartitionsOutput = (inputDF
                       .writeStream
                       .foreachBatch(foreach_batch_func)
                       .trigger(processingTime='<trigger time>')
                       .start()
                      )
```